# Prevent click event on parent element when image clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to stop a second piece of JS running as a result of the click event propagating to the parent element but I am stuck.

I have the following HTML for rows in a table:

```
<tr id="DEMO01-P" role="row" class="odd">
   <td><img id="DEMO1" src="../imagedir/edit.png" onclick="Edit(this.id);">Info here</td>
   <td>And here</td>
</tr>
```

I have a click event on the tr `like` this:

```
  jQuery('#system-tbl tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var self = jQuery(this);
    if ( self.hasClass('selected') ) {
      self.removeClass('selected');
    } else {
      table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
      self.addClass('selected');
    }
    DO STUFF....
  });
```

I also do something else if the user clicks on the `img` inside the tr using `onclick="Edit(this.id);"`:

```
function Edit(system_id) {
    alert("Edit: " + system_id);
    window.location.href = "/go-to-page/";
};
```

How do I stop the `tr` event in the call to `Edit(this.id);`? Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
<td><img id="DEMO1" src="../imagedir/edit.png" onclick="Edit(event,this.id);">Info here</td>
```

and

```
function Edit(e,system_id) {
::
e.stopPropagation()
}
```